# Why tensorflow at my jupyter notebook is not working even after installing tensorflow using "conda install tensorflow"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, jupyter

I have tried the following command in anaconda prompt:

$ conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow

$ conda activate tensorflow_env

but the notebook returns the following error:

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

in

----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the error as text instead of a link to an image. The link might get broken in the future and a text is more searchable.

Comment: Make sure you are starting your Jupyter notebook from a prompt where the environment is activated (or if you do it from Anaconda Navigator, make sure you are choosing the environment in the combo box before launching the application).